# I keep receiving and address error for my assembly language

Tags: assembly, 68000

So I am creating an assembly language for the following:

```
 X = 5
 Y = 7
 FOR I = 1 TO 9
    Y = Y + I
    IF T(I) = J(I) + X THEN J(I) = T(I) * 4 - Y
               ELSE J(I) = J(I) - T(I) 
END_FOR
```

and keep recieving a

```
"Address Error: Instruction at  418 accessing address  44f
Execution halted"
```

The code I have so far is:

```
    ORG $400

    MOVEA   #T,A0
    MOVEA   #J,A1
    MOVE.B  #1,D0       //D0 is a counter to hold I
    MOVE    #5,D1       //X = 5
    MOVE    #7,D2       //Y = 7
NEXT    
    ADD D0,D2       //Y = Y + I
    MOVE    (A0),D3     
    MOVE    (A1),D4
    MOVE    D4,D5       //D5 is a temp copy of J(I)
    MOVE    D5,D1
    CMP D5,D3       //IF T(I) = J(I) + X
    BNE ELSE
    SUB D2,D3
    MULU    #4,D3
    MOVE    D3,(A1)     
    BRA END_LOOP
ELSE    
    SUB D3,D4       //J(I) = J(I) - T(i)
    MOVE    D4,(A1)
END_LOOP
    ADDA    #2,A0       //POINT TO NEXT ELEMENT IN T
    ADDA    #2,A1       //POINT TO NEXT ELEMENT IN J
    ADD #1,D0
    CMP #9,D0
    BNE NEXT
    MOVE.B  #4,D0
    TRAP    #15     //; halt simulator

* Variables and Strings
T   DC.B    6,2,5,4,9,7,3,1,0
J   DC.B    5,7,1,9,2,5,6,6,1

    END $400        //; last line of source
```

What am I overlooking?

Comment: btw I am using the Easy68K Editor/Assembler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll execute without any errors (not sure if it does the right calculations but that's up to you since it's homework) if you change all your `MOVE`,`ADD`,`SUB`,`CMP` to `MOVE.B`, `ADD.B`, `SUB.B`, `CMP.B`. I'm assuming `.B` since your variables are declared `DC.B`. Even if you're not getting errors you should specify the size. **Note** the main ones that need changing are the `MOVE`s that access memory, for the reasons below, but they should all really be specified.

Anyway the error occurred at: `MOVE  (A1),D4`. If you trace through and look at the registers you'll see the similar instruction before that (`MOVE (A0),D3`) was reading a WORD rather than a BYTE into `D3`: `D3=00000602`. It read the first two bytes from `T` into `D3`. `MOVE  (A1),D4` also wants to read a WORD, this time from `J`.

However, since you told the assembler to `DC.B`, it aligned the memory so that you can access your arrays as BYTEs as opposed to WORDs. Since your `MOVE` instructions and such were defaulting to `MOVE.W`, you could also change `DC.B` to `DC.W`, and the error would go away. Don't do that though, just showing you how and why the error occurs, you should specify the sizes as I mentioned above.

Also take note that with instructions like `MULU`, if you only want to multiply single BYTEs together you should make sure that the higher BYTEs of your register(s) are zeroed out, since it multiplies together at least a WORD from each operand. Since you haven't moved anything more than a BYTE into `D3` the higher BYTEs are all 0 anyway.

Another thing, `END $400` should usually be something like `END START`, ie:

```
    ORG $1000
START:
...
END START
```

**EDIT**: Just thought I'd point out (if it wasn't already obvious) that you should fix your increment of `A0` and `A1`, ie. read JustinP's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know about Easy68K, but in other assemblers that I have known wouldn't an instruction called DC.B allocate bytes? In which case you'd need adda #1,a0 to iterate through these?

Comment: This and `MOVE (A0),D3` should be `MOVE.B (A0), D3` (memory access must be (word-)aligned on 68k). Probably other stuff as well.